# Jaxb2Marchaller loading/validating classes on application deploy taking too much time

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-ws, jaxb2

I'm facing a problem on my project that is the time that **Jaxb2Marshaller** takes to validate/parse all classes genereated by **XJC** on deploy time. In my context configuration I have the following configuration:

```
<bean id="jaxbMarshallerOpe" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="contextPaths">
        <list>
            <value>com.src.integration.generated.pojo.client</value>
            <value>com.src.integration.generated.pojo.product</value>
            <value>com.src.integration.generated.pojo.company</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="marshallerProperties">
        <map>
            <entry key="jaxb.encoding" value="UTF-8" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Inside of each directory mapped on my context file, we have several classes that Jaxb2Marchaller executes the validation/parsing in deploy time that is causing a problem with an SLA for deploy that we have. My question is, how can I make this validation occurs after the deploy? Or do I have another approach for this situation so I can reduce the deploy time and still have my services working?

Comment: Hi Guys, I really need some help on this. Anyone from Spring, can you help me on this? This is really becoming a problem to me and my client.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try the [lazy-init](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/oxm/jaxb/Jaxb2Marshaller.html#setLazyInit-boolean-) flag of the `Jaxb2Marshaller`.

Comment: Arjen thanks for your help. This approach is on the table too, but I was trying to find another way to optimize the createContext functionality so I can maintain this on deploy time. Another question that I was thinking is to configure the lazy by profiling. For example: In DEV enviroment we enable the lazy init but on Production enviroment we enable it. Does anybody know how to do that or even if it's possible?

Comment: It is possible, using bean profiles. See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-definition-profiles